# TFS - Access file via HTTP

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to download the latest version of a file in TFS via HTTP of FTP? For example, http://server:8090/tfs/path/to/file.cs

When you browse TFS (using a URL similar to above), it opens the file in the browser on a frame within the page, I'm trying to open just the full content of the physical file. There is a download button, but I'm looking for a direct URL to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the REST API to download the latest version of a file:

**For TFVC :** ([Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/items/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0))

```
   GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Project}/_apis/tfvc/items?download=true&path=<File Path>
```

e.g.:

```
http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName}/_apis/tfvc/items?download=true&path=$/Scrum-TFVC/DownloadT/DownloadT/Program.cs
```

**For Git:**  ([Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0))

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository name or ID}/items?download=true&scopepath=<File path>
```

e.g.:

```
http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Git-Scrum/_apis/git/repositories/389e8215-1fb2-4fdc-bd04-ebc8a8a4410e/items?download=true&scopepath=/WebApp01/WebApp01/Startup.cs
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after. FYI for anyone else, you can take the download=true param out if you want the request to return the file contents in the response rather than as an attached file

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with TFS online you can user http
https://your_company.visualstudio.com

According to TFS documentation, you should be able to connect in your TFS by web browser:

Look at doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/connect-team-projects?view=vsts

Look at the section "Connect from the web portal"

Comment: Thanks for your response, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to open just the full content of the physical file, browsing in the way you suggest will open the code directly on a panel in the browser page